# Как сделать поиск в листе ?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

У меня есть поисковая строка, при нажатии открывается список. Мне нужно при нажатии чекбоксов , всё писалось в поисковую строку. Ну а при нажатии больше 3 чекбоксов. Писалось 4 из 12 выбрано.

```css
.body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.btn-space {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.save_button {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
}
div.btn-group.btn-lgg {
    margin: -5;
    padding: -5;
}
.btn-lg {
  width: 362px;
  position: relative;
}
.btn-lgg {
  width: 243px;
  height: 46px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width:300px;
  height:40px;
  padding-left: 25px;

}
input::placeholder {
  text-indent: 0.1em;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

div>hr {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background: gray;
}
h1{
margin-top: 40px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Block</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="struct.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <!-- Optional theme -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row" style = "margin-left:-10px; margin-top:200px;margin:display;">
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group">
       <form>
             <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Страна, курорт или отель"  data-toggle="dropdown" autofocus>
     <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"style="margin-left:-295px;""></i>
     </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox">Турция 123</li>
       <div>
       <hr>
       <h6 class="dropdown-header">Популярные курорты</h6>
       <hr>
       </div>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> How</li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> Are</li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> You</li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> You</li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> You</li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> You</li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> You</li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> You</li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> You</li>
       <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox"> You</li>
     </ul>
   </form>
  </div><!--
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделаем просто и надёжно. В инпут добавим value. Получится `<input type="checkbox" value="1">`. Затем в необходимое место добавим `<output id="rezultat"></output>`.
Заголовок формы поменяем, например так `<form name='Sum'>`. И осталось написать обработчик на js:

```
var s = document.forms.Sum,
    d = s.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not([value]), input[type="checkbox"][value=""]');
  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) // чтобы не было написано NaN, убираем в disabled пункты, где не прописаны значения
    d[i].disabled = true;
s.onchange = function() { // начало работы функции сложения
  var n = s.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]'),
      itog = 0;
  for(var j=0; j<n.length; j++)
    n[j].checked ? itog += parseFloat(n[j].value) : itog;
    if (itog > 3) {
      document.getElementById('rezultat').innerHTML = 'Вы выбрали ' + itog + ' из 14 пунктов';
    }
}
```

Идея решения была [тут](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/08/checked.html)